# iOS 11 Navigation bar large title have black color when push on pop view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios11

I have a problem with the new navigation bar for iOS 11.

In root view set new navigation by code:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAlways;
}
```

Then from root view, I pushed to another view and set code navigation bar by

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
}
```

It works well. However, when push and pop view a black color appeared like the image below:

[image]

I don't know why the black color appeared on this view although I did not set back ground for navigation bar is a black color for the whole screen in my app.

Someone have any idea for the problem. Please drop me some suggestion to solve that bug. Thanks.

Comment: Show your AccountVC code

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437160/ios-11-black-bar-appears-on-navigation-bar-when-pushing-view-controller) has the correct answer

Answer (score 32):

I solved this issue by setting navigation controller background colour in the UIViewController class where I am getting black colour.

Here is the code I used :

```
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I have tried changing background colours and shadows in story board but it doesn't seem to fix this issue. Hopefully this answer is still relevant here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just what I was looking for. Is it possible to accomplish this using the storyboard instead of the code?

Answer (score 9):

I solved this in my own app by subclassing UINavigationController and setting its `view.backgroundColor`.

Comment: Yes. The dark affect by code set clear color at the root navigation.

Comment: I agree, but the color shown is darkest than the one you choose, and I don't know why.

Comment: @sancho Shadows, maybe?

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue with simple extension

```
extension UINavigationController {

    @IBInspectable var backgroundColor: UIColor {
        set {
            self.view.backgroundColor = newValue;
        }
        get {
            return self.view.backgroundColor ?? UIColor.black;
        }
    }

}
```

You can change background color from storyboard!