# iOS 11 black bar appears on navigation bar when pushing view controller

Tags: swift, navigationbar, ios11

I have this weird bug only in iOS 11, in lower iOS, everything works fine.
The problem is that whenever pushing to a view controller, there is a black space appears on top of the navigation bar. Has anyone else experienced this problem and how to fix it?

[image: Pushing]

Comment: post your code, figuring out something from an image is a shot in the dark

Comment: @mlegg it is just normal pushViewController. This bug happens every where in the app, not just at one place. Besides, in iOS10, iOS9 and iOS8, it is working fine.

Comment: can you check your `print(view.safeAreaInsets)`

Comment: I check it and it was all zeros.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I have the same issue

Comment: I also have the same issue, Did any one  find the right solution for that.

Answer (score 54):

The problem is that in case of double velocity that your view size is smaller then the navigation controller view size.

So when you scrolling trough the view's frame is changing during changing of content offset and it's doubles velocity as well. 

That would explain that behaviour. 
Please try following to fix the problem.

```
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

You should add this line at your `UIViewController`, `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: Saviour :) Works perfectly

Comment: Excellent solution

Comment: Works like a charm with UICollectionViewController and UISearchController. Thanks a ton!

Comment: This is still the best approach

Answer (score 6):

You can add a constraint of height 44 to the search bar for iOS 11.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: This solution will decrease the height of search bar in iPhone X.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and fixed it by removing the following piece of 
code from the parent controller during viewWillDisappear

`self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)`